# Access MySQL and PHP after installation

Tags: mysql, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

After I installed Apache2, MySQL, MySQL Client, phpMyAdmin  and PHP on my Ubuntu 13.10, I tested the Apache2 using 127.0.0.1 and it works. I would like to learn how I can access MySQL and create PHP scripts for my testing website and upload to a web server.

Your help and information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access MySQL from command line by typing in a terminal:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password]
```

where `[username]` is the user you setup during install and `[password]` is the password for that user.  If the password has special characters (such as $ or !) then you can leave the -p blank and it will prompt you for the password.

As far as phpMyAdmin, you need to edit the default Apache2 conf (usually located at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/apache2/apache.conf).  Make a backup (`cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.bak`) add these lines to the end of apache2.conf:

```
# Include phpmyadmin

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Save the file.  Then, restart Apache2 with:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Now, you should be able to access phpMyAdmin by typing `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` in the address bar of your browser.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information I got permission denied when I tried to copy the file to backup cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.bak Regards, Inung

Comment: I got unknown database when I enter mysql -u [username] -p [password]

Comment: Sorry, you need to do all these commands as sudo or as root.

Comment: Thanks for the information and help, are there any way to use WorkBench? should I just upload myfile.php file to /etc/apache2? Thanks again for helping, Regards, Inung

Comment: If you are wanting to make a php file (like a page on the webserver) you can add it to the whatever the root directory of the website is (usually /var/www/).  After that, my knowledge of this subject is mostly exhausted.